# Which should I choose , "Butterfly" or "Deer"?

Tags: word-choice

I remember there is a phrase which means **feeling the heart beating fast because of nervousness.**

is it

> "have some deer running in my heart"

or

> "have some butterflies flying in my heart".

Answer (score 3):

## Butterflies in the stomach

The physical sensation in humans of a "fluttery" feeling in the stomach.
It's caused by nervousness and the release of adrenaline.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterflies_in_the_stomach

Comment: The OP wants something for the heart.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those are common phrases, to say the least. Of the two, ‘butterflies’ is the better metaphor as butterflies flit about quickly, although it may come across as an unintentional mangling of the common metaphor “butterflies in my stomach”.

You might want to try a different phrase. Comparing the heart-rate to that  of a mouse could work, since mice have extremely quick heart-rates and are associated with fear/jumpiness and scurrying about.

You could instead describe the heart as ‘buzzing’ or ‘pounding’ - the former emphasising the speed of the heart and the latter emphasising the intensity.

Personally, I would choose based on what stands out most from the surrounding text; if metaphors are common in the preceding paragraphs, I’d instead use the simpler adjectives. Still, that’s not my choice to make.